# How to group consecutive integers in a scala array?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

Let’s say I have an array like the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4
```

I want many sub-arrays of contiguous numbers whose sum of every contiguous pair is less than 10

```
1 2 3 4 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4
```

How do I code it in scala in a functional idiomatic way?

```
// example no. 1
>Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)...???
res0: List(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(6))
// example no. 2
>Array(3, 8, 1, 9, 1, 3)...???
res1: List(Array(3), Array(8, 1), Array(9), Array(1, 3))
```

Comment: What does it have to do with reactivex and category-theory?

Comment: It can be solved with reactivex or category-theory

Comment: I see no relevance. Also it's unclear what are you trying to achieve, do you want to split array into elements that are below or above given threshold?

Comment: No I want to split an array into sub-arrays of consecutive elements whose sum of every contiguous pair is less then 10, see above question for details and examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `foldRight` makes it easier to use `head` and `tail` to build the resulting `List`.

```
val grouped = Array(3,8,1,9,1,3).foldRight(List.empty[Array[Int]]){case (n,acc) =>
  if (acc.isEmpty) List(Array(n))
  else if (acc.head.head + n < 10) n +: acc.head :: acc.tail
  else Array(n) :: acc
}  // List(Array(3), Array(8, 1), Array(9), Array(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (although it's a very inefficient way):

```scala
def group(threshold: Int)(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Seq[Int]] =
  seq.reverse.tails.find(_.sum < threshold) match {
    case None => Nil
    case Some(Nil) => Nil
    case Some(subSeq) => 
      subSeq.reverse +: group(threshold)(seq.drop(subSeq.size))
  }

group(10)(Array(3, 8, 1, 9, 1, 3))
List(Array(3), Array(8, 1), Array(9), Array(1, 3))
```